# My iPad won't accept my Apple ID password

Tags: ipad, apple-id, password

My new iPad won't accept my Apple ID password. I get a "your Apple ID has been disabled" message. If I go to my laptop everything works fine.  I've logged on and off the iPad, changed my password, pondered to Apple emails, etc., but am at a loss now on how to fix the problem.  Any advice for this new Apple user is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try signing into find my friends and then signing out.  I know it sounds dumb, but this honestly might work.